# How do I attach an access token to a Google Sheets V4 request?

Tags: android, google-api, spreadsheet

I discovered how to obtain an access token for the Google Spreadsheets V4. However... I have no knowledge or of any source on how to append the access token to the credentials:

```
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
```

In previous Google Sheets v3 API, I could fully understand how the access key is simply added in a requestfactory or some similar function call which would then return the service object.

Is there a way to do the same in Google Sheets v4?

Comment: have a look at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1SheetsBaseServiceRequest-g.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method

setAccessToken (); see the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get.html#setAccessToken(java.lang.String))

For more details see [official dev page](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1SheetsBaseServiceRequest-g.html)